# 'System.Type' does not contain a definition for 'GenericTypeArguments' with (dynamic)

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, reflection

I am trying to get the type of a dynamic linq column using

```
var args = ((dynamic)linqColumn).PropertyType.GenericTypeArguments;
```

then comparing on the possible types names :

```
if (args.Length > 0 && args[0].Name == "DateTime")
    ProcessDateTimeType();
else if (args.Length > 0 && args[0].Name == "Double")
    ProcessDoubleType();
```

This works on a Windows Vista with .NET 4.0, but does not work with a Windows Server 2003 also with .NET 4.0. An error `'System.Type' does not contain a definition for 'GenericTypeArguments'` is throwed.

I need GenericTypeArguments only for nullable types.

Any idea ?

**Remarks**

- `linqColumn` is obtained via `var linqColumn =
  linqTableType.GetProperty("COLNAME");`
- `linqTableType` is obtained via `'Type linqTableType =
  Type.GetType("MYNAMESPACE." + "TABLENAME");`
- Code is executed inside
  a web service

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenericarguments(v=vs.100).aspx - supported on Windows Server 2003 SP2 - check that you have installed SP2

Comment: `GenericTypeArguments` wasn't added to `System.Type` until .Net 4.5. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.generictypearguments(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Actually yes Preston is right, I was looking at GetGenericArguments - are you sure you are building for .NET 4.0 on Vista?

Comment: The project is with VWD 2010 Express, and the target framework is .NET Framework 4. However I just noticed Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1 is installed on the Vista but not on the Windows Server 2003. Could it be the origin of the error, eventough the project is targeting .NET 4 only ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Preston mentioned in the comments, the `GenericTypeArguments` property was added in .NET 4.5.

4.5 is an in-place upgrade to 4.0; even though you're targeting 4.0, the 4.5 APIs will still work when you use reflection or `dynamic`.

Try limiting the `dynamic` code to just the part that retrieves the property type; from that point on, you know the value is a `Type`, so you can use early binding:

```
Type propertyType = ((dynamic)linqColumn).PropertyType;

// Visual Studio should now warn you if you try to use:
// var args = propertyType.GenericTypeArguments;

var args = propertyType.IsGenericType && !propertyType.IsGenericTypeDefinition
    ? propertyType.GetGenericArguments()
    : Type.EmptyTypes;
```

Comment: Thanks, as the need was for nullables types only (Nullable``1 DateTime, ...), so using `Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(linqColumn.PropertyType)` worked also.